# Is there a GUI debugger for shell scripts

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash, shell

Debugging bash scripts on command line is complicated.

Is there a good GUI based debugger available for debugging bash scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure that always wanting *GUI based* debugging is a useful habit. A lot of things are easier *without* GUI, and `bash` debugging usually is easier in the terminal (without any GUI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A useful trick is to start your (executable) bash script with

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
```

at least during the debugging phase; you'll get a lot of helpful messages from bash. See [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

If your script is not supposed to be used in a terminal (e.g. it is invoked from a [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry) you could also use the [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command.

At last, I believe that `bash` is not the right tool to do complex scripting. If your script is becoming complex or bigger than a few dozens of lines, consider switching to a better scripting language (like [GNU guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [python](https://www.python.org/), [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), etc...). In general, you should not code a lot in `bash`. Having pain to debug a bash script is usually a symptom that you should recode that script in a better language.

You may also find useful to *generate* your shell script. [autogen](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/) could be useful for that.

Answer (score 9):

Download [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/) eclipse plugin (update site didn't work for me) which allows editing bash scripts. Install this via `Help -> Install new software -> Add -> Archive`.

Download [basheclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/basheclipse/) and extract the contents to your eclipse `plugins` directory plugin.

Restart eclipse. Create a new Eclipse project `BashTest`.

Add a file `myscript.sh` to the project:

```
#! /bin/bash

. _DEBUG.sh

echo 'kshitiz'
echo 'This is a test'
x=1
y=3
z=3
```

Add `_DEBUG.sh` to your project (Its in the downloaded zip for `basheclipse`).

Go to `Run -> Debug configurations` and create a new configuration under `Bash script` category. Select `myscript.sh`.

[image]

Then click `Debug`. Open `Debug` perspective.

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Shell script -> Interpreters` and ensure that interpreter is `/bin/bash`. For me the default was `/bin/dash`.

[image]

Set a breakpoint in the script. For some reason the right click menu does not show the option to set the breakpoint but `Ctrl+Shift+B` should work.
[image]

Run the script `Run -> Run as -> Run shell script`.  The breakpoint will hit but it won't be able to find your script source (wierd eh!). Just click `Select Bash script` and select `myscript.sh`.

Now you can step through the code and analyze the variables:
[image]